# How does python handle a simultaneous reference to a variable via self and as a class attribute(static)?

Tags: python

More importantly, if someone can explain the output of the following code.

```
class myclass:
  num = 10
  def mymethod(self):
    print("PrevValue of self.num->",self.num)
    print("Prev Value of myclass.num->",myclass.num)
    self.num+=10
    myclass.num+=20
    print("PostValue of self.num->",self.num)
    print("PostValue of myclass.num->",myclass.num)

obj1 = myclass()
obj2 = myclass()
obj2.mymethod()
obj1.mymethod()
```

The output of the above code is as follows.

```
('PrevValue of self.num->', 10)
('Prev Value of myclass.num->', 10)
('PostValue of self.num->', 20)
('PostValue of myclass.num->', 30)
('PrevValue of self.num->', 30)
('Prev Value of myclass.num->', 30)
('PostValue of self.num->', 40)
('PostValue of myclass.num->', 50)
```

The line 7, i.e *self.num+=10* seems to refer the supposed class attribute num, and add a value to that using self. The next line the same variable is being accessed as a class variable. So it is reasonable to assume that the variable is being used both as a static and a self variable. How can a variable be both static and a self variable ? (Or there is something that I could be missing here)

Comment: If these were to be added after above the lines of code
`print(myclass.num)
print(obj2.num)
print(obj1.num)
`
The output would be :
'50
20
40`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `num` attribute starts as a class attribute but then this:

```
 self.num+=10
```

can be expanded to `self.num = self.num + 10` . What's happening is: First we look for a instance property called num, we don't find it, then we look for a class property called num, and we use that to set the instance property value. In this moment you have both a instance and a class property using the same `num` name.

EDIT

The explanation above is only partially correct. First, the `num` property is searched for a [**iadd** method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.iadd) and if it fails to find that (which it does, on account of num being of an immutable type, it will try to do the reassignation procedure above

Comment: Sorry to being that guy and nitpick: "can be expanded to ..." is NOT true in general. You can check that by using a mutable object like a list. The `+=` operator will call to the inplace add operator, (unexpectedly) modifying the static class attribute

Comment: Maybe the easiest way to keep the answer correct and not overcomplicate things would be to add "given that in this scenario num is an immutable object, can be expanded to ...". The inverse is not true because a mutable object can not implemen the `__iadd__` method. Again, overcomplicating things.

Comment: actually, after a quick test regarding this, the class instance appears to be unmodified

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7BDoIwDIbve4oSLywuxCEnE0@efQJCDI4hmm0QNw57@tlNwMRe2v75@/2dvBtGU4YgVGstXP0l9ny8v6Rw9EQAy8wazsAPaVE41pyV7NiQJHSyB@1vWiKoy61U/XIWK65FvN9vgE1WUawrxGAaR@waTpNQ/KCUkOn9NG51JCLskMhgNmJozUN2fxYVDd9HWdUAZBksxhA@ "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: Did you miss my "using a mutable object like a list"? I know your answer is correct for this specific case (that's why I already +1'd it).

Comment: my mistake.... so then it's actually creating an instance property because of the int's immutability.... i guess that could be considered an undesirable side effect .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152229/discussion-between-mariussiuram-and-omu-negru).